# Docker tag and push for cloud provider in ansible

Tags: docker, ansible

I am building a docker container using ansible, but I need to also tag this container for GCP (Google Cloud Platform). I can do this on the command line with

```
docker tag app:latest gcr.io/my-project-12314514/app:latest
```

but I don't see how to do this using ansible. I use the docker_image command to build my container.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local

  tasks:
  - name: Build container
    docker_image:
      name: app
      path: web_app/
      pull: no
      state: build
```

the tag item only overwrites the "latest" tag. I can

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local

  tasks:
  - name: Build container
    docker_image:
      name: app
      path: web_app/
      pull: no
      state: build
  - name: Tag for GCP
    docker_image:
      name: gcr.io/my-project-12314514/app
      path: web_app/
      pull: no
      state: build
```

I have copy pasted all to created a "tagged" container and this seems to work, but it looks clunky. Can this be done more elegant?

Comment: doesnt `tag` field do what you are asking for ? https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/docker_image_module.html

Comment: as far as I can see it you use it to overwrite the tag. Eg. web_app:latest is the default and you can change it to web_app:v1 by setting the tag equal to v1

Comment: Why don't you directly build your image with the correct name/tag (the gcp one) the first time and use it like so ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The examples in the documentation suggest how you would do this:

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/docker_image_module.html#examples

```yaml
tasks:
- name: Build container
  docker_image:
    name: app
    path: web_app/
    pull: no
    state: build
- name: Tag for GCP
  docker_image:
    name: app
    repository: gcr.io/your-project/your-repo
    tag: your-tag
    push: yes
```